# Should I add non indexed subdomains to Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain

My web app consists of static pages / landing pages that should be indexed and dynamic pages which is the outcome / results of what the user is using my web app for which cannot not be indexed.

All static pages are accessible by using the www. sub domain.

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/landing-page
www.domain.com/contact
```

All dynamic web app pages use a separate sub domain which represents the server location (pertinent information to the user using the web app).

```
fr.domain.com/random_dynamic_path
phx.domain.com/random_dynamic_path
nyc.domain.com/random_dynamic_path
```

Static and landing pages can not be accessed by using a dynamic sub domain, the page will just redirect to the www. subdomain to avoid duplicate content.

Example:
`fr.domain.com/contact` (or any other subdomain) will redirect to `www.domain.com/contact`

The `www.` sub domain has a sitemap and proper robots.txt file while the other sub domains have a robots.txt file which blocks all bots. Even if a bot were to try and view a users dynamic link it would result in a 404 error (dynamic links can only be viewed by the user who created them).

So my question is; Since all other sub domains aside from the www. can not be crawled by bots, as well as the fact that the actual static and landing pages can only be accessed by the www. subdomain - should I still add the other sub domains to Google Search Console?

Currently I have `http:// https:// http://www. https://www` all added separately to Search console like it says to do but I was under the impression I didn't have to add my other sub domains since they are dynamic, can't be crawled by bots, and should never be able to be indexed anyways since there is no content to view unless a real user is using the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you don't need it**.

If you have already blocked your subdomain from search engine, then search console **can't find, any data about your site**, so what's the purpose of that property?

Since, Google allowed up to 100 property in search console, so feel free to test it, and delete it later. But I am 100% sure, you will not going to get any data on all of properties, since you blocked it on robots.txt